# How Do I Sort A List Of Objects Based On Highest Grouping?

Tags: sorting, kotlin

If I have a list of objects, how do I sort them based on the largest group?

e.g.  I read this csv to a list of objects

```
FirstName, LastName, Age
Michael, Moore, 64
John, Doe, 22
John, Brown, 44
Peter, Piper, 46
John, Johnson, 14
Peter, Rabbit, 5
```

If I group by FirstName I get

```
FirstName, Count
Michael, 1
John, 3
Peter, 2
```

If I sort descending by the count I get

```
FirstName, Count
John, 3
Peter, 2
Michael, 1
```

How do I now sort the first list by the order of this sorted group?

```
FirstName, LastName, Age
John, Doe, 22
John, Brown, 44
John, Johnson, 14
Peter, Piper, 46
Peter, Rabbit, 5
Michael, Moore, 64
```

So far I have:

```
val people: List<Person> = readNames(csv)
val group = positions.groupingBy { it.firstName }.eachCount()
val sorted = group.toList().sortedByDescending { (key, value) -> value }
```

Comment: Convert the first comment to an answer so I can accept

Answer (score 0):

After grouping, the first name has become a key for the importance of that name in the sorted list.

```
people.sortedByDescending { group[it.firstName] }
```

You could also sort the list of people by the frequency of first name occurrence, though the operation will be heavier as counting is performed on each item rather than all at once via your grouping.

```
people.sortedByDescending { person -> people.count { it.firstName == person.firstName } }
```

Answer (score 0):

Create your `eachCount` Map which contains each name with related number of occurences. Then sort the original array by the previously determined counts:

```
val sorted = ps.groupingBy { it.fn }.eachCount().let { counts ->
    ps.sortedByDescending { counts[it.fn] }
}
```